# Passing a string variable to another procedure to assign a value to it in a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I want to pass a a string variable `"Sheets(2).Cells(i, 41).Value"` to the procedure `Sub prcdTariff_calc` that will assign in a loop a value to that variable in order to pass it on to another function,`Function Tariff_calc`.
The problem is with `Sub prcdSum_year_IR()`. I tried already to play around with the datatypes (String / Double) in the procedures and also `CDbl(quality)` etc... Is there a way to pass on the variable `quality` into the loop in `Sub prcdTariff_calc` ? Thanks for advice.

```
  Option Explicit
    Dim  price As String
    Dim i As Byte
    Public  sum_tariff As Double
    Dim tariff As Double, period As Double, quality As Double


    Function Tariff_calc(a As Double, Optional b As Double = 1, Optional c As Double = 1) As Double
    Tariff_calc = a * b * c
    Debug.Print b
    End Function

    Function Price_calc(a As Double, Optional b As String = 1, Optional c As Double = 1) As String
    Price_calc = Format(a * b * c, "0.00   €/MWh")
    End Function

    Sub prcdTariff_calc(Optional a As Double = 1, Optional b As Double = 1, Optional c As Double = 1)
    For i = 2 To 43
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(i, 1).Value = 1 Then
            a = Sheets(2).Cells(i, 19).Value
            'I also tried b = val(quality) here
'I experimented here by referring to newly created procedure Sub [prcdquality() quality = Sheets(2).Cells(i, 41) End Sub] and back here then b=quality; and it worked         
            sum_tariff = sum_tariff + Tariff_calc(a, Val(b), c) 'I tried val(b), but it still shows 0 in Debug.Print b above.

            price = Price_calc(a, CStr(b), c)
            lblPrice.Caption = lblPrice.Caption & price & vbCrLf
        End If
    Next i
    End Sub

    Sub prcdSum_year_Firm()'works fine
    prcdTariff_calc
    lblUnitCost.Caption = Format(sum_tariff, "0.00    €/MWh")
    End Sub

    Sub prcdSum_year_IR()
    quality = Sheets(2).Cells(i, 41)
    prcdTariff_calc b:=quality
    lblUnitCost.Caption = Format(sum_tariff, "0.00    €/MWh")
    End Sub
```

Comment: This `quality = "Sheets(2).Cells(i, 41).Value"` assignment does not mean that quality contains the value of the cell `Sheets(2).Cells(i, 41).Value`. It will just contain the string _Sheets(2).Cells(i, 41).Value_.  And I assume with _here it doesn't work_ you mean the line `prcdTariff_calc 1, quality` throws an error, right. Please understand that "*does not work*" is not really helpful. Also have a look at the basics of using [subs and func](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-sub/) You also might have other issues in your code as you do not use `Option Explicit` and global variables.

Comment: If you don't know the data type you can usually declare it as Variant and let Excel sort the problem. However, your calculation needs a numeric value. You can convert the cell value to a number with Val(Sheets(2).Cells(i, 41).Value). Of course, if the cell contains a string the numeric value will be zero which doesn't sit well with your multiplication. So, something like Iif(Val(Sheets(2).Cells(i, 41).Value),Val(Sheets(2).Cells(i, 41).Value),1) should do the job. If passed directly to the function make sure it is passed ByVal.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I use `Option Explicit`. The error message that occurs is `Type mismatch` with reference to `b` in the part `Tariff_calc(a, b, c)` of the procedure `Sub prcdTariff_calc`. Moreover, the variable  `quality = "Sheets(2).Cells(i, 41).Value"` should always be numeric as the column includes numbers only. I am not sure if the `IIF` function is of any use in this case. I need to find a way that the procedure `Sub prcdTariff_calc` is extracting the number of the given Cell(i,41). Apologies if I missunderstood anything.

Comment: Sorry but you seem not to understand. Your variable `quality` will contain the string `Sheets(2).Cells(i, 41).Value`. It will not contain the value of cell(i,41) of Sheets(2). For that you have to remove the double quotes and write `quality = Sheets(2).Cells(i, 41).Value`. Do you see the difference? That is a real basic mistake.

Comment: Thanks, got it! I've tried this already before, but it will only return 0 as value for `quality`. Though there is something strange: I modified `Sub prcdTariff_calc` by referring to another newly created procedure which defines `quality = Sheets(2).Cells(i, 41).Value` (so identitcal to your suggestion) and then back in `Sub prcdTariff_calc` define `b = quality`... and then it worked. But this is exactly the same thing as written in `Sub prcdSum_year_IR()` ?!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem by modifying the code by declaring the variables a,b,c inside the loop of procedure. It works fine now.

```
Function Tariff_calc(a As Double, Optional b As Double = 1, Optional c As Double = 1) As Double
Tariff_calc = a * b * c
End Function

Function Price_calc(a As Double, Optional b As String = 1, Optional c As Double = 1) As String
Price_calc = Format(a * b * c, "0.00   €/MWh")
End Function

Sub prcdTariff_calc(Optional a As Double = 1, Optional b As Double = 1, Optional c As Double = 1)
For i = 2 To 43
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(i, 1).Value = 1 Then
        a = Sheets(2).Cells(i, 19).Value 'annual tariff
        If optIR.Value Then
           b = Sheets(2).Cells(i, 41) 'quality factor
        End If
        If optQuarter.Value Then
            c = Sheets(2).Cells(i, 21 + q) 'period factor Quarter
        ElseIf optMonth.Value Then
            c = Sheets(2).Cells(i, 28 + m) 'period factor Month
        ElseIf optDay.Value Then
            c = Sheets(2).Cells(i, 27)
        End If

        sum_tariff = sum_tariff + Tariff_calc(a, b, c)

        price = Price_calc(a, CStr(b), c)
        lblPrice.Caption = lblPrice.Caption & price & vbCrLf
    End If
Next i
lblUnitCost.Caption = Format(sum_tariff, "0.00    €/MWh")
End Sub
```